# Reload updated package in R

Tags: r, rstudio

I used to develop some package for R. So, this is an iterative process where I need to check the working of the package in between by installing it via rstudio, and then again adding some necessary functionalities. So, I used the following process:

1. create a R package
2. install it via command prompt: R CMD install <{package_name}>
3. load the package in rstudio as, library(package_name)
4. Check the necessary functionality
5. detach package in rstudio using, detach(package:{package_name})
6. remove package via command prompt as: R CMD remove <{package_name}>
7. add/update package
8. repeat steps 2 - 7,until package is fully developed.

Now the problem is that everytime I close rstudio after step 5, otherwise updated package after installation is not reflected in R. 
 So, How can I avoid to close rstdio everytime; and always get updated copy of installed package. In other words, I don't want to close rstudio everytime. I have found that detach( ) is not effective.
**Note:** I use rstudio only for checking the functionality of package. I check,build for building packages on command prompt using R CMD check/build commands

Comment: RStudio Session->Restart R. If you use RStudio to make/develop the packages you get almost all of the hard parts of 1:8 for free.

Comment: I use "Source on Save" and work interactively to develop my packages. I only do a full build occasionally.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, what is "source on save". How and where you do it?

Answer (score 0):

RStudio has functionality for building packages that I does what I think you have described.

Basically, use 'new project' and select the R-package option or just open an old project using the '.Rproj' file

Then use the build and reload each time you make a change to the package
and want to reload the package in (see pic).

Seems to work OK for me.

[image: Rstudio build image]

See link for more details:
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486488-Developing-Packages-with-RStudio

Comment: I am not using rstudio build package process. I tried it, but there were some issues with documentation part.